# insert in delete values in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, crud

New to MySQL, I have  user table that holds data when users signup. At sign up 1 email is required but I want them to be able to add additional emails to the mail col of the User table. Is this possible? I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('email@fake.com') WHERE user_id = 1;
```

and found out INSERT won't respect 'WHERE'. First is this even the correct approach? If not, how can add multiple values and be able to delete a one of multiple values later if the user chooses to?

Comment: Best way is to create a second table with all alternate emails using same userid as user table

Comment: `INSERT` inserts new data, `UPDATE` updates existing. Please read some mysql/sql basics.

Comment: I was thinking that but was trying to avoid it

Comment: Update would change the original value. I more want to add another value the email column

Comment: I decided to create another separate table with accessing the user table via Primary key. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your simple solution is using [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `email` = CONCAT(`email`, ',', 'new_email@mail.com') 
WHERE id = 1
```

**But**! Here comes the problem, when your user wants to `delete` an email.
You'll have to explode your current `email` string, remove value from it, and do an update like:

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `email` = 'string of emails' 
WHERE id = 1
```

That's why storing `email`s should be either in separate fields, like `email1`, `email2` if you have 2 emails **only**.

If you allow users to have a lot of emails - then you should add a new table, called `user_emails`, for example, with scheme like:

```
user_id | email
```

Then selecting emails become something like:

```
SELECT `email` FROM `user_emails` WHERE `user_id` = 1
```

Adding email is just another insert:

```
INSERT INTO `user_emails` VALUES (1, 'new_email')
```

And removing is:

```
DELETE FROM `user_emails` WHERE id = 1 AND email = 'new_email'
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is a relational db language, and as such promotes relating tables for times like these. As @Fabio commented, your simplest approach would be to have another table of email address, and replace your `email` column on `users` with an `userEmailId` column that allows you to relate multiple rows in this `email` table back to this `user` by having each row in `email` contain this `userEmailId`and the actual email data.

Adding a table is the simplest approach and the only other way I can think of achieving this is by adding more columns to `user` for additional emails. You could then use `update` on a `user` you want to add an email to by updating a null email column.

A third approach, which may work depending on how you're using these queries and if it's part of larger php, node, or the like application, would be to append a new email to a current email and separate the two with some sort of character not allowed in an email, a space character could be a simple example. Within your server language you can separate this string into your individual emails. Using `update` can achieve this, but you will have to subquery to carry over current data within the `email` field upon adding a new email.